# Find matrix with size m satisfy A^n = I(m)

Tags: mathematical-expressions

I've just began to learn mathematics at university, and I have met this problem, that is:

`find all matrix A(m) that A^n = I(m)`.

Can you help me solve this?

Comment: Are you trying to write a program to do this?  If so, you need to provide more of an explanation about the code part.  If not, it's off-topic for Stack Overflow - you want https://math.stackexchange.com/ (though I imagine they'll expect a more detailed explanation over there as well).

Comment: Thanks a lot, i just want to find a solution for this problem in mathematics.